# Apache connecting to SSL SNI reverse proxy

Tags: apache-2.2

I have reverse proxy set up in my DMZ, *ApacheDMZ* which is configured using SNI. I'm adding a new Apache server *Outside* that needs to use mod proxy to access certain resources through ApacheDMZ.

Both are CentOS 6.x.

I am getting a `403 forbidden` when I visit the pages on Outside and `No hostname was provided via SNI for a name based virtual host` in the ApacheDMZ logs.

How can I correct this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [this bug](https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=55782) where this should be fixed; which version are you on, and do you have `ProxyPreserveHost On` enabled?